# Send message from one class to another class

Tags: python, class, wxpython

**Problem:** I have a frame (`FirstFrame` class), which has a button that calls another frame (`SecondFrame` class). When I click the button in the `SecondFrame`, I want this frame to close and to send a message ('I'm the first frame', see below) to the `FirstFrame`.

This is my code so far:

```
import wx

class FirstFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="First Frame", size=(400,400))
        self.UI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def UI(self):
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND) 
        b = wx.Button(self.panel1, label='second window', size=(100,100), pos=(100,100))
        b.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB)        

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)  

    def OnB(self, event):
        frame = SecondFrame()
        frame.Show()

class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Second Frame")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        txt = wx.StaticText(panel, label="I'm the second frame!")
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Close window and send message", pos = (100,100))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)

    def onClose(self,event):
        self.Close()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
app = wx.App(False)
FirstFrame(None, title='')
app.MainLoop()
```

I just don't know how to connect the two classes. That is, after clicking the button in the second frame, how to communicate with the first frame that called it. Any suggestions? What I want to obtain is something similar as this, after clicking the button on the `SecondFrame`:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What I want to obtain is something similar as this, after clicking the button on the SecondFrame:* -- I added some code to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is, after clicking the button in the second frame, how to
>   communicate with the first frame that called it. Any suggestions?

When you create the second Frame, send `self` to it:

```
frame = SecondFrame(self)  #Inside the first Frame, self is the first Frame
```

Or, equivalently:

```
first_frame = self
frame = SecondFrame(first_frame)
```

In the second Frame's constructor do this:

```
class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, first_frame):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Second Frame")
        self.first_frame = first_frame
```

Then, in the second Frame's onclick handler, you can do this:

```
def onClose(self,event):
    self.first_frame.do_something("I'm the first frame")
    self.Close()
```

And in the first Frame, you can do this:

```
class FirstFrame(wx.Frame):
    ...
    ...
    def do_something(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg  #Save the message
        print(msg)      #Do something else with the message....
```

Or, in your particular case:

```
    def do_something(self, msg):
        wx.StaticText(self.panel1, label="I'm the first frame")
```

Note that in your first Frame constructor:

```
def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="First Frame", size=(400,400))
```

you don't use the parent or title parameter variables, so specifying arguments for those variables does nothing:

```
FirstFrame(None, title='')
```

The title won't be blank, it will be "First Frame".  You want to do something like this:

```
class FirstFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, the_title="First Frame", the_parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(
                self, 
                the_parent, 
                title=the_title, 
                size=(400,400)
        )
        self.UI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
```

Then, if you want to use the defaults you can call the first Frame constructor like this:

```
app = wx.App(False)
FirstFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

And, if you want to use another title, you can write:

```
app = wx.App(False)
FirstFrame("Testing")
app.MainLoop()
```